# How to mock Django's now function in all application functions

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I am attempting to mock Django's now() function in order to spoof the time used in my application. I can easily mock the now() function within my test file, but the mock replacement doesn't seem to percolate down recursively into my applications functions. Here is the code I am using:

```
# file - tests.py:

import datetime
import pytz
import mock

from django.test import TestCase

# this is the fake time I am using
TESTING_DJNOW = pytz.timezone('US/Central').localize(datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 14, 8, 0))


# This is the function that replaces django.utils.timezone.now()
def mocked_djnow():
    return TESTING_DJNOW

@mock.patch('django.utils.timezone.now', side_effect=mocked_djnow)
class ViewsTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['users.json', 'views_data.json'] # our initial test data

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.client.login(username='fred', password='secret')

    def test_view(self, *args):
        from django.utils.timezone import now
        tm = now() # returns datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 14, 8, 0, 
                   # tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Central' CDT-1 day, 19:00:00 DST>)

        resp = self.client.get(reverse('myapp:viewfunc1'))



# file - myapp.views.py:

from django.utils.timezone import localtime, now

@login_required
def viewfunc1(request):
    # returns datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 16, 1, 11, 6, 964624, tzinfo=<UTC>)
    tm = now() # returns current datetime
```

Is is possible to patch Django functions like now() throughout the entire application? If so, what am I doing wrong? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't like to use mocks for date because of constant pain. Instead I suggest you to give [FreezeGun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun) a try. It has all sorts of datetime fiddling utils you need in your tests and wherever.

Example from docs with timezones:

```
from freezegun import freeze_time

@freeze_time("2012-01-14 03:21:34", tz_offset=-4)
def test():
    assert datetime.datetime.utcnow() == datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 14, 3, 21, 34)
    assert datetime.datetime.now() == datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 13, 23, 21, 34)

    # datetime.date.today() uses local time
    assert datetime.date.today() == datetime.date(2012, 1, 13)
```

Also it has cool features like manual ticks and context managers. The lib is about 500 lines of code and very well written, so you can read it from A to Z within an hour to understand how it works.